# Object of type 'Menu' is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I made simple api with Django Rest framework.

[models.py]

```
from django.db import models

class Menu(models.Model):
    place = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    mon = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    tue = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    wed = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    thu = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    fri = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    sat = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
    sun = models.CharField(max_length=3000)
```

[serializers.py]

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models

class MenuSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Menu
        fields = '__all__'
```

[urls.py]

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Menu.as_view(), name='menu')
]
```

[views.py]

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from . import models

class Menu(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        all_menu = models.Menu.objects.all()

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=all_menu)
```

When I connect to /menu, It throws

```
TypeError at /menu/
Object of type 'Menu' is not JSON serializable
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pass as response queryset direcly. But queryset is not serializable object. And this is why you need serializers.

Just serialize data before return it as response with serializer class, like this:

```
class Menu(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        all_menu = models.Menu.objects.all()
        serializer = MenuSerializer(all_menu, many=True)  
        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```